# How to format an object into a nice HTML table?

Tags: html, powershell, html-table

I have 2 scripts

script1 has the following:

```
$exportObject = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
$exportObject | Select-Object
```

in script2, i am calling script1 to do something and piping the output to an `-ov`

```
& "script1.ps1" -ov $outputValue
$outputValue
```

this is what i get

[image: output]

Now I am trying to send that variable output in an email body.

```
Send-MailMessage -From $FromEm -Subject $Subject -To "user@domain.com" -Body $outputValue -BodyAsHtml -SmtpServer $SmtpServer -Port $Port -Credential $Creds -UseSsl
```

Send_mailMessage won't accept ArrayList variable like this, so i am converting to HTML then string

```
$outputValue = $outputValue | ConvertTo-HTML <# -As Table #> | Out-String
```

this sends the following in the email body:

[image: c]

its good but i would like to make it look like a table, with borders styling, etc.

how can i do that?

i am thinking something like this:

```
$outputValue = $outputValue | ConvertTo-HTML | foreach-object{if($outValue.header) {<th></th>} else <td></td>} | Out-String
```

though thats a rough idea of what i have in mind and not sure how to do it exactly

Comment: checkout this SO post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17708405/powershell-html-tables

Comment: @trebleCode based on the answer, i tried this: $outputValue = $outputValue | ConvertTo-HTML -Head '<style>th,td {text-align:center;}</style>' | Out-String ...however, it had no formatting effect. same output in the body. i think it has no effect because i am converting to string after that, which is mandatory because -Body only accepts strings :/

Comment: @Matt i am already using that -Body $outputValue -BodyAsHtml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can be as creative as you like with HTML styling of course.
Below code styles the table like this:

[image]

```
# just some fake data here
$exportObject = @(
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        'Server' = 'Server1.com'
        'Cube' = 'Cube1'
        'Connection Details' = 'Connection changed!'
    },
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        'Server' = 'Server2.com'
        'Cube' = 'Cube2'
        'Connection Details' = 'Connection Unchanged!'
    },
        [PSCustomObject]@{
        'Server' = 'Server3.com'
        'Cube' = 'Cube3'
        'Connection Details' = 'Connection changed!'
    }
)

function ConvertTo-HTMLTable ($obj) {
    # Accepts a System.Data.DataTable object or an array of PSObjects and converts to styled HTML table

    # add type needed to replace HTML special characters into entities
    Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Web

    $sb = New-Object -TypeName System.Text.StringBuilder
    [void]$sb.AppendLine('<table>')
    if ($null -ne $obj) {
        if (([object]$obj).GetType().FullName -eq 'System.Data.DataTable'){
            # it is a DataTable; convert to array of PSObjects
            $obj = $obj | Select-Object * -ExcludeProperty ItemArray, Table, RowError, RowState, HasErrors
        }
        $headers = $obj[0].PSObject.Properties | Select -ExpandProperty Name
        [void]$sb.AppendLine('<thead><tr>')
        foreach ($column in $headers) {
            [void]$sb.AppendLine(('<th>{0}</th>' -f [System.Web.HttpUtility]::HtmlEncode($column)))
        }
        [void]$sb.AppendLine('</tr></thead><tbody>')
        $row = 0
        $obj | ForEach-Object {
            # add inline style for zebra color rows
            if ($row++ -band 1) {
                $tr = '<tr style="background-color: {0};">' -f $oddRowBackColor
            } 
            else {
                $tr = '<tr>'
            }
            [void]$sb.AppendLine($tr)
            foreach ($column in $headers) {
                [string]$val = $($_.$column)
                if ([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($val)) { 
                    $td = '<td>&nbsp;</td>' 
                } 
                else { 
                    $td = '<td>{0}</td>' -f [System.Web.HttpUtility]::HtmlEncode($val)
                }
                [void]$sb.Append($td)
            }
            [void]$sb.AppendLine('</tr>')
        }

        [void]$sb.AppendLine('</tbody>')
    }
    [void]$sb.AppendLine('</table>')

    return $sb.ToString()
}


$headerBackColor = '#4F81BD'  # backgroundcolor for column headers
$oddRowBackColor = '#DCE6F1'  # background color for odd rows

$style = @"
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <title>Report</title>
    <meta name="generator" content="PowerShell" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <style type="text/css">
    body {
        font-family: Verdana, Arial, Geneva, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-size: 12px;
        color: black;
    }
    table, td, th {
        border-color: black;
        border-style: solid;
        font-family: Verdana, Arial, Geneva, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-size: 11px;
    }
    table {
        border-width: 0 0 1px 1px;
        border-spacing: 0;
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }

    td, th {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 4px;
        border-width: 1px 1px 0 0;
        text-align: left;
    }
    th {
        color: white;
        background-color: $headerBackColor;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    </style>
"@

$body = '{0}</head><body>{1}</body></html>' -f $style, (ConvertTo-HTMLTable $exportObject)

Send-MailMessage -From $FromEm -Subject $Subject -To "user@domain.com" -Body $body -BodyAsHtml -SmtpServer $SmtpServer -Port $Port -Credential $Creds -UseSsl
```

Two examples to do table styling that mimic the MS Word `Grid Table 5 Dark Accent 5` can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55086954/how-to-generate-an-email-with-powershell-containing-unknown-table-sizes-with-off)

Hope that helps

Comment: huge props to @Drew for helping me get the pscustomobject here https://stackoverflow.com/a/56878918/8397835 , and combine it with your answer, wala! this is working :D

Comment: @Cataster Sorry, I left a variablename in there due to copy-paste .. `$obj = $DataTable | Select-Object ...` should be `$obj = $obj | Select-Object ...`. Fixed in the answer now.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what's going wrong for you. This works for me:

```
$Body = Get-ChildItem C:\Windows\ -File | 
    Select-Object -Property Name, Length, LastWriteTime -First 10 |
    ConvertTo-Html -As Table -Head '<style type="text/css">th,td { text-align:center; }</style>' |
    Out-String

Send-MailMessage -SmtpServer $SmtpServer -UseSsl -Subject $Subject -To $To -From $From -Body $Body -BodyAsHtml
```

Comment: ya this is not working at all for me, the format is still the same :/
  $outputValue = $outputValue | Select-Object -Property Server, Cube, 'Connection Details' -First 3 | ConvertTo-HTML -Head '<style>th,td {text-align:center;}</style>' | Out-String

Comment: @Cataster Define "not working". Do you get an error message? Which command errors? Is the HTML created valid? If you save it to a file and open it in a browser does it work?

Comment: its not working as in the formatting remains the same in the email body, no table borders as i am expecting. i think its because of Out-String

Comment: @Cataster Try posting the HTML output at the end of your question.

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"> <html xmlns="w3.org/1999/xhtml"> <head> <title>HTML TABLE</title> </head><body> <table> <colgroup><col/><col/><col/></colgroup> <tr><th>Server</th><th>Cube</th><th>Connection Details</th></tr> <tr><td>Server1</td><td>Cube1</td><td>Connection Changed!</td></tr> </table> </body></html>

Comment: @Cataster Are you perhaps running the Send-MailMessage call from within a module you import? If that is the case, try using `Import-Module xyz -Force` or if that fails put `Remove-Module xyz` first. Once a module is loaded, PowerShell will not respect the changes in it. Closing the PowerShell instance and reopening it would also do it.

Comment: @Theo nope, no modules. i also closed the session and started a new one. same thing, the format in the email is not changing to the table styling (borders, etc..)