# how to create pscustomobject from arraylist dynamically?

Tags: powershell

this post is supplementary to this thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56876792/8397835)

Basically, I have 2 scripts

script1 has the following:

```
$exportObject = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
$exportObject | Select-Object
```

in script2, i am calling script1 to do something and piping the output to an `-ov`

```
& "script1.ps1" -ov $outputValue
$outputValue
```

this is what i get

[image: op]

i would like to covert `$outValue` to `pscustomobject` ***dynamically***, because Theo's answer (in link above) requires pscustomobject, and my `$outValue` is an array list/select object...

basically the pscustomobject would hold values like this, but this is not dynamic and instead hardcoding the keys/values.

```
$outValue = @(
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        'Server' = 'Server1.com'
        'Cube' = 'Cube1'
        'Connection Details' = 'Connection changed!'
    }
)
```

i am looking for something like this:

```
$outValue = $outValue | foreach-object () { @(
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        $key = $value
    }
}
)
```

Comment: The answer from Theo is actually an array of pscustomobjects. I think I have a very, very stupid way of doing this but I will need to test first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be highly volatile but is working on several machines I have tested.

This should get you going at creating "dynamic" Arrays with `PSCustomObject` members.

```
$array = @()
Foreach($Object in $exportObject ) {
    $i = -1
    $Goal = -($Object | gm | Where-Object {$_.MemberType -like "noteproperty"}).count

    $temp = New-Object pscustomobject
    Do {
        $temp | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name (($Object | gm)[$($i)].Name) -Value ($Object."$(($Object | gm)[$($i)].Name)")
        $i--
    }While($i -ge $Goal)

    $array += $temp
}
```

This is obviously not the best practise but quick and dirty is how most things get done in my experience.

Then use `$array` in your other function provided by Theo, `ConvertTo-HTMLTable $array`

Comment: This is actually close to what I am looking for: ), but because there is -1, -2, -3 objects, it still is kinda hard coding, dont you think? It's great that no actual values are defined, but if its possible to condense it down for the pscustom object to automatically identify the number of objects/properties incoming fron $exportObject/$outputValue, and create objects as needed it would be perfect

Comment: Updated. I actually had a lot more fun making this one, I may even have use for it at some point.

Comment: Trying it right now :D, btw, offtopic, this is an array @(), but what is this called? @" "@?

Comment: hey Drew, i just tried this, and i tried outputting $array to test it, it is outputting the values, but the column/headers are missing (Server, Cube, Connection Details). is there a way to include those? because if i implement this ConvertTo-HTMLTable $array, wouldnt the colun names be missing?

Comment: Try doing an `Out-Host` for `(($Object | gm)[$($i)].Name)` within the while loop and see what it outputs. Also an `@""@ allows you to create a variable with a multi-line string.

Comment: but after that is -Value. wouldnt it error out? unless you mean make anotehr copy of that in the while loop? also, @""@ thanks for explaining it, but i always called it annotation, is there an official name for it?

Comment: Play around with trying to extract the name from the `Get-Member` to add it as the name of the `pscustomobject` Mine works at the moment so there may be something going on with yours.. The `@""@` is called an interpolated here-string. Have a read of the [PS Punctuation guide](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/PSPunctuationWallChart_1_0_4.pdf)

Comment: i just applied this to Theo's function and it sent me the email with the nice table :D also, both column and data are there..though its weird how the column name wasnt printing on console

Comment: Drew, for some reason, the ordering is getting rearranged around. is it possible to modify the function and retain the objects order?

Comment: nvm, with Theo's answer, it improves your answer and also generates the nice order we want :) https://stackoverflow.com/a/57028423/8397835