# What does a Query have to do with Get-Member?

Tags: powershell

I have 2 scripts.

**Script1** has the following:

```
function Query($Query) {
    $SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection 
    $SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server=$DB_Server;Initial Catalog=$Database;Integrated Security=SSPI" 
    $SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand 
    $SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection 
    $SqlCmd.CommandText = $Query 
    $SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter 
    $SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $SqlCmd 
    $DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet 
    $a = $SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)
    $SqlConnection.Close() 
    $DataSet.Tables[0]
}

#create .net array object for csv export
$exportObject = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
#create ordered dictionary so column names come out in the ordered they were created
$rowObject = [ordered]@{}

$connection_string = "Connection Timeout=120;User Id=UID1;Data Source=datasource.com;Password=password12!553"

$rowObject.'Connection Details' = $connection_string

#INSERT connection string into Table
Query "UPDATE [$someTable]
SET [connection_string] = '$connection_string'
WHERE [cname] = '$cinput' AND ([pserver] = '$pinput'"

$exportObject.Add((New-Object PSObject -Property $rowObject)) | Out-Null

$exportObject | Select-Object
```

Now in script2, I call script1 and "out-variable" the object then convert it to a `PSCustomObject` to use it with an HTML table function (not relevant to this thread so wont include in code. more info on that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56876792/8397835)).

**Script2:**

```
& ".\script1.ps1" -ViewConnection "$cinput" -OutVariable xprtOut | Format-Table -Wrap

#converting xprtOut from Arraylist to pscustomobject to be used with ConvertTo-HTMLTable
$Arr = @()
foreach ($Object in $xprtOut) {
    $i = -1
    $arrayListCount = -($Object | gm | Where-Object {$_.MemberType -like "noteproperty"}).Count

    $customObj = New-Object PSCustomObject
    do {
        $customObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name (($Object | gm)[$($i)].Name) -Value ($Object."$(($Object | gm)[$($i)].Name)")
        $i--
    } while ($i -ge $arrayListCount)

    $Arr += $customObj
}
```

when I run script2, i get the following errors:

```
gm : You must specify an object for the Get-Member cmdlet.
$arrayListCount = -($Object | gm | Where-Object {$_.MemberType -l ...

Cannot index into a null array.
... dd-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name (($Object | gm)[$($i)].Name) ...
```

After some long debugging, I found the root problem: by removing the `UPDATE` query statement from script1, script2 stopped erroring and it started working just fine.

So the question is, why would the query statement in script1 be problematic? What does it have to do with the object conversion?

Comment: the error msg is pretty danged specific ... at that point in your code, you either had nothing at all OR at least one $Null object in the `$Object` variable.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey i dont understand..is the query counted as null? how/what/why?

Comment: @Drew since you helped me with creating the conversion, could you possibly look at this post? Maybe you might have an idea what is going on :)

Comment: the error msg means that `$Object` is empty at that point OR that one of the items in the variable is empty. you need to find out what is in the `$Object` variable when you get that error. not just "is it empty", but "are there any empty items". [*grin*]

Comment: @Lee_Dailey its something to do.with the Query in script 1, because wen I remove it I don't get the error, I just dont understand why the query would be getting passed to the out variable in acript2

Comment: from what i can understand of your 1st script ... the data for the 2nd COMES FROM the 1st script. so changes there seem guaranteed to have an effect on the the 2nd script. you need to find what in the 1st is giving you blank items OR add a filter to the 1st script that only passes on non-null items.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey I did find out, it's the query statement in the script1 causing the issue. But why is it and what does it have to do with being null or even passing to script2, I have no clue

Comment: your `$Object` gets it's info from `Foreach ($Object in $xprtOut) ` & that comes from `& ".\script1.ps1" -ViewConnection "$cinput" -OutVariable xprtOut` ... so the 1st script is the source of your glitch.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey i know that script1 is the glitch/problem source, particularly, it has to do with the Query. Ive now found out the issue is because of the adapter in the Query function thanks to jrv here https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/0e171c40-073e-43ed-b9ae-67e479791aa7/what-exactly-is-the-null-part-in-this-error?forum=winserverpowershell

Comment: kool! glad that you found the glitch ... if you have the time, add that as an answer to your question here - NOT the link, but the idea. links die over time, so links are not recommended.

Comment: If you format the output of script1 like you have done here `| Format-Table -Wrap` then you change the object from what you think it is.

Consider the difference between `$a = Get-Process` and `$a = Get-Process | FT` as a minimal example.

Comment: @Ash I did consider that as a root cause, and I commented it out, but didnt help. The root cause is definitely the Query in script 1, I just dont understand why it would be and why does script 2 care about it at all if it's not being passed on the pipeline I suppose.

Comment: It is still not needed. I've not looked at the rest of your issue yet.

Comment: @Ash I see. The reason I have FT is because I want the Wrap feature, and unfortunately, select object doesn't have that and if the value is too long it gets truncated, that's why I added FT

Comment: I would format your output at the very end of your script. I have added a suggestion below. It may or may not help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an issue with formatting the output of the first script when you output it as a variable that I have already mentioned. If you do thing the issue is with the Update statement, then I'd check your syntax is parsing correctly in PowerShell. It is also not clear how your function is receiving the $DB_Server and $Database values. I'm not absolutely sure this will fix your issue, but I think the code for your query function could probably be simplified, and here is a minimal example that works for me.

```bsh
function Query {
    Param (
        [parameter(Mandatory=$true,Position = 0)][string]$SqlConnection,
        [parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position = 1)][string]$Data
    )

    # Create a new connection
    $SqlClient = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection($SqlConnection)
    $SqlClient.Open()

    # Submit the query
    $Query = "UPDATE <tablename> SET <column_name> = '$Data' WHERE <column_name> = '<value>'"
    # You may want to comment out the rest of the function here and see how your Query looks.
    $Command = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand($Query,$SqlClient)
    $DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
    $DataAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter($Command)
    $DataAdapter.Fill($DataSet) | Out-Null

    # Close and return your data. You may want to dispose of the client too.
    $DataSet.Tables[0]
    $SqlClient.Close()
    $SqlClient.Dispose()
}

$UserConnection = "Connection Timeout=120;User Id=UID1;Data Source=datasource.com;Password=password12!553"
$SqlConnection = "Server=<Server\Instance>; Database=<Database_Name>; Integrated Security=True; Connect Timeout=15"
Query -SqlConnection $SqlConnection -Data $UserConnection
```

You then may want to loop through a custom object of SQL Connections and the User Connections you want to add and create your output object that way. This should maintain the output in the order you provided them in.

```bsh
$Export = $Connections | Foreach-Object { Query -SqlConnection $_.SqlConnection -Data $_.UserConnection }
return $Export
```

Then you can follow on with the actions of script two as below. I'm not sure you need a separate one.

```bsh
foreach ($obj in $Export) {
    # Do stuff here.
}
```

Comment: this didnt really resolve my issue, what i ended up doing is just using Invoke-sqlcmd for this UPDATE statements and that made it work